# Mostrar imagenes en App desde Firebase Storage con Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firebase-storage

tengo el siguiente problema:

El usuario desde la aplicación sube una imagen para que se visualice en la opción del perfil, para esto utilizo Firebase storage como contenedor y obtengo la imagen con Picasso.get() pero antes utilizo el método Compressor para reducir su calidad y subir el archivo en formato jpg, pero al subirla se guardan con el formato "application/octet-stream" siendo que en el código se especifica el formato.

la imagen se sube sin problemas pero como no es JPG no se pueden visualizar en la aplicación en tiempo de ejecución.

llevo días implementando diferentes códigos pero no consigo que la imagen se suba en jpg, abajo dejaré los códigos.

Compressor: Método para comprimir la imagen

```
public class CompressorBitmapImage {
    static int height;
    static Bitmap thumb_bitmap;
    final File file_thumb_path;
    final Context context;
    final int width;

    public CompressorBitmapImage(File file_thumb_path, Context context, int width, int height) {

        this.file_thumb_path = file_thumb_path;
        this.context = context;
        this.width = width;
        CompressorBitmapImage.height = height;

    }


    /*
     * Metodo que permite comprimir imagenes y transformarlas a bitmap
     */

    public static byte[] getImage(Context context, String path, int width, int height) {
        CompressorBitmapImage.height = height;
        final File file_thumb_path = new File(path);

        new CompressorBitmapImage(file_thumb_path, context, width, height);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (thumb_bitmap != null) {
            thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,80,baos);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Código para subir la imagen comprimida:

```
public class ImageProvider {

    StorageReference mStorage;

    public ImageProvider() {
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    public UploadTask save(Context context, File file) {
        byte[] imageByte = CompressorBitmapImage.getImage(context, file.getPath(), 500, 500);
        StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(new Date() + ".jpg");
        mStorage = storage;
        UploadTask task = storage.putBytes(imageByte);
        return task;
    }

    public StorageReference getStorage() {
        return mStorage;
    }

}
```

Muchas gracias, cualquier ayuda me servirá.

Answer (score 1):

Si ya estas definiendo un "Storage Reference" usa esta para crear una referencia a la imagen. No veo donde llamas save().

Lo que debes realizar es obtener el arreglo de bytes de la imagen, definiendo los valore apropiados para `getImage()`:

```
byte[] data =  getImage(Context context, String path, int width, int height);
```

y posteriormente usar `UploadTask` para subir la imagen, es importante uses los listener para poder detectar un problema al tratar de subir la imagen.:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
          //Ocurrió error!!!
          Log.e("UploadTask", "Ocurrió un error al tratar de subir la imagen");
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Se sube con exito!.
            Log.i("UploadTask", "se subió imagen exitosamente.");  
    }
});
```

Revisa **[Sube archivos con Cloud Storage en Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=es)**

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, en primer lugar, gracias por responder, implementé el código que me enviaste pero aun asi, las imagenes se siguen subiendo en formato "application/octet-stream", el save que me comentas es el siguiente

Comment: mImageProvider.save(EditProfileActivity.this, mImageFile).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                mImageProvider.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                    final String urlProfile = uri.toString();